# C# show console spinner (waiting indicator) while running other code

Tags: c#, event-handling

In my app I'm trying to use simple download indicator.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        ConsoleSpinner spin = new ConsoleSpinner();
        spin.Start();
        DownloadFile();
        spin.Stop();
        Console.ReadKey();
        Environment.Exit(0);
    }

    private static void DownloadFile()
    {
        Uri url = new Uri("https://website.com");
        HttpWebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(url) as HttpWebRequest;
        try
        {
            using (HttpWebResponse response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse)
            {
                using (Stream file = File.OpenWrite(@"C:\test.txt"))
                using (Stream input = response.GetResponseStream())
                {
                    input.CopyTo(file);
                }
            }           
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
             throw;
        }
    }
}
```

Any help is appreciated.

### UPDATED

Here is solution that I asked for.

```
class Program
{
    private static BackgroundWorker worker = new BackgroundWorker();
    static void Main()
    {
        worker.DoWork += worker_DoWork;
        worker.WorkerSupportsCancellation = true;
        Console.Write("Downloading ");
        worker.RunWorkerAsync();
        DownloadFile();
        worker.Cancel.Async();
        Console.ReadKey();
        Environment.Exit(0);
    }

    private static void DownloadFile()
    {
        Uri url = new Uri("https://website.com");
        HttpWebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(url) as HttpWebRequest;
        try
        {
            using (HttpWebResponse response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse)
            {

                string savePath = @"C:\download\test.txt";
                using (Stream file = File.OpenWrite(savePath))
                using (Stream input = response.GetResponseStream())
                {
                    input.CopyTo(file);
                }
            }           
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
             throw;
        }
    }

    static void worker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        int i = 0;
        while (true)
        {
            if (worker.CancellationPending) break;
            i++;
            Console.CursorVisible = false;
            switch (i % 4)
            {
                case 0: Console.Write("|"); break;
                case 1: Console.Write("/"); break;
                case 2: Console.Write("-"); break;
                case 3: Console.Write("\\"); break;
            }
            Console.SetCursorPosition(Console.CursorLeft - 1, Console.CursorTop);
            Thread.Sleep(200);
        }
    }
}
```

### UPDATED #2

Complete [solution](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/cbragg/console-application-waitbusy-spin-animation/).

Comment: It looks like you're expecting your `ConsoleSpinner` (or download) code to be running on another thread of execution, but that spinner is blocking your (single) thread from even beginning to download the file.

Comment: I don't think this question is answered in the given question, this question was specifically about doing async work loads and updating the console, besides i had an answer!

Comment: Guess I need to use `BackgroundWorker`.. [example](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/cc221403%28v=vs.95%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

Comment: @AntoshaShmonoff tasks are your friend, use `await request.GetResponseAsync()` in your downloaderAync method , then await it using `while (await Task.WhenAny(downloadTask, Task.Delay(1000)) != downloadTask) { Console.Write("."); }` there are many examples out there.

Comment: maybe here is a better example [link](https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/625473/backgroundWorker-in-csharp)

Comment: @MichaelRandall I have many functions in my code: files downloading and database requests, so I need universal solution..

Comment: @AntoshaShmonoff tasks, async away pattern. Just research it , you will get there

Comment: @AntoshaShmonoff you just have to ask a better question

Answer (score -4):

Have you tried making the DownloadFile function call asynchronously with Task?  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh195051(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: This neither answers the question nor going to be helpful for code shown.